# TypeConverter for "SecureString" does not support converting a string

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, attached-properties

I've got an WPF application that I'm implementing using the MVVM pattern. In this application I'm trying to get the password from a PasswordBox via an attached property. However, I'm getting the error seen above and I'm not sure why I'm getting it. Here's what I have:

**XAML**

```
<PasswordBox x:Name="passwordTextbox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="31" Margin="316,194,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="208"
                     FontSize="16" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}"
                     vm:PasswordBoxAttachedProperty.EncryptedPassword="PasswordSecureString, Mode=Twoway, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged" />
```

**Attached Property**

```
using System.Security;
using System.Windows;

namespace QMAC.ViewModel
{
    public static class PasswordBoxAttachedProperty
    {


        public static SecureString GetEncryptedPassword(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (SecureString)obj.GetValue(EncryptedPasswordProperty);
        }

        public static void SetEncryptedPassword(DependencyObject obj, SecureString value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(EncryptedPasswordProperty, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty EncryptedPasswordProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("EncryptedPassword", typeof(SecureString), typeof(PasswordBoxAttachedProperty));
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably wanted to write

```
vm:PasswordBoxAttachedProperty.EncryptedPassword=
    "{Binding PasswordSecureString, Mode=Twoway, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

instead of

```
vm:PasswordBoxAttachedProperty.EncryptedPassword=
    "PasswordSecureString, Mode=Twoway, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged"
```

Comment: Thanks. I've looked at that line no telling how many times today. Doesn't surprise me that I overlooked something that simple.